# Understanding folder placement in meteor create appName --full

Tags: visual-studio-code

This Meteor app was created using `meteor create alosh --full`, looking at the folder structure in Visual Studio Code, there is a line [image: api\links] as in the image attached.

Is links a sub folder or api? If so, why is "links" not listed under "api" and instead next to it?
If not, then why `import { Links } from "../../api/links/links.js"`; in the file fixtures.js showing "links" a sub folder of "api".

And BTW, how does such "sub folder" gets created where it sits next to "api" and not under it? And what is the reason/benefits?

Thanks

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `links` is listed next to `api` because so far it's the only thing inside of the `api` directory if you were to create more sub-apis it'd be listed underneath it as you'd expect. It's just a vscode UI.

Now, why does it sit underneath `api` and not to next to it you may ask. It's because `api` directory is intended to group all of your models' logic so sooner or later you'd end up creating a directory to hold them all.